# TypeScript+AngularJS: Change Style of ng-model from controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following problem:

This index.html creates a table:

```
<table class="table-bordered">
    <th>
        <td ng-repeat="column in sheet.columns">{{column}}</td>
    </th>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in sheet.rows">
        <td>{{row}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="column in sheet.columns">
            <div>
                <input style="border: none; text-align: center" ng-model="sheet.cells[column+row]" ng-change="sheet.change(sheet.cells[column+row], column, row)"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The SheetController fills the table with values from the dataService.data.

```
setup(){
    this.data = this.dataService.data;
    this.rows = [];
    this.cells = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < this.data.months[this.month].days.length; i++){
        this.rows.push(i+1);
        this.cells[this.columns[0] + this.rows[i]] = this.data.months[this.month].days[i].date;            
    }
}
```

Now I want to change the background-color of some cells, like:

```
this.cells[...].style.add("background-color", yellow);
```

I know this isn't possible because it's the ng-model value, not the real field, is there a workaround?

Comment: What's`this.cells[...]` supposed to contain? List of DOM elements or what?

Comment: No, this is the point. There are just the values shown in the table

Comment: Then use just [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).

Comment: yep, ngStyle should do it